# How to add 404 not found to flask

Tags: python, flask

I would like to add a method to redirect to a template in case of not finding a url.

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('settings')

    app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=views.home_page)
    app.add_url_rule('/login', view_func=views.login_page, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    app.add_url_rule('/logout', view_func=views.logout_page)
    app.add_url_rule('/movies', view_func=views.movies_page, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    app.add_url_rule('/movie/<int:movie_key>', view_func=views.movie_page)
    app.add_url_rule('/new-movie', view_func=views.movie_add_page, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

I have found the following method but it doesn't work for the project I am working on.

```
from flask import render_template

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit more a bit the problem you have? What route are you trying to call to get the 404 what result do you get when you call this endpoint? Also how does the code look with the error handler included? Because in the end the snippet you posted should work.

Comment: Can you also please tell us your directory structure ?